# How can I create a custom installer process for a project?

Tags: php, symfony, installation, composer-php

I have created a Symfony project that will be duplicated in other companies.

I would like to simplify the installation of this project for the other companies by using a command like "composer create-project" while asking questions which will modify the `.env` according theirs answers.

How could I accomplish this with Composer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`composer create-project` simply clones the VCS repository of a package, and then executes `composer install`. ([Docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project)).

There is no other magic to it.

So you simply create a package with your custom `composer.json`, declaring whatever dependencies you want for bootstrapping the project:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "foo/bar": "^1.1",
        "fizz/buzz": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

To create the logic for aking the user questions and doing other things in response (e.g. adding stuff to `.env`), you can take advantage of [Package Events](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#package-events). Specifically `post-create-project-cmd`.

So you'd add to the skeleton `composer.json` something like this:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "foo/bar": "^1.1",
        "fizz/buzz": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts":
    {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php bin/your_custom_setup_script.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Read more about setting up scripts [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts).

The actual coding of your custom script you'll have to do yourself. It can do whatever you need to help bootstrap the installation (updating configuration, creating directories, clearing cache, etc).